# Drag and drop SKNode without touching it

Tags: ios, swift, drag-and-drop

I have an SKNode on SpriteKit, which I basically want to be able to drag around the screen, but without having to touch it! Imagine I press the screen anywhere. I then want my SKNode to keep its distance to my finger, so that when I drag it I can see it.

I have this working but the object snaps to the touch.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches{
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        circle.position = location


    }
}


override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches{
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        circle.position = location

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?){

        let touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch!
        let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let previousLocation = touch.previousLocationInNode(self)
        let distanceX = touchLocation.x - previousLocation.x
        let distanceY = touchLocation.y - previousLocation.y

        circle.position = CGPointMake(circle.position.x + distanceX, circle.position.y + distanceY)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a classic basic problem in game engineering.

## There are **two** solutions...

---

**First** solution: when finger first goes down, make a note of the "grab" delta, being the delta from the position of the object, to, the finger.

When the finger moves each time to new position P, **subtract** the "grab" delta from P before **setting the position** of the object to P.

"It's that easy"

---

**Second** solution: each time the finger *moves*, don't bother at all with the position P of the finger.

Instead, calculate the *delta the finger moved from the previous frame*.

(So, simply store the previous position each time so you can calculate that - some systems give you the previous position as a property since it's so common, indeed some systems just give you the delta automatically as a property!)

Then just **move the object** by that delta.

"It's that easy"

---

Here is precisely the first solution, in iOS/SpriteKit

```
class FingerFollower: SKSpriteNode {
    
    var grab: CGVector = CGVector.zero
    // "grab" is the usual term for the delta from the object
    // to where the finger "grabbed" it...
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        
        let t: UITouch = touches.first! as UITouch
        let l = t.location(in: parent!)
       
        grab = (l - position).vector
    }
    
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        
        let t: UITouch = touches.first! as UITouch
        let loc = t.location(in: parent!)
        
        position = loc - grab
    }
    
    // NOTE this code uses the absolutely obvious overrides for
    // subtraction etc between vectors, which you will need in 100%
    // of spritekit projects (Apple forgot about them)
}
```

---

Here is precisely the second solution, in iOS/SpriteKit

```
class FingerFollower: SKSpriteNode {
    
    func setup() {
        
        // NOTE, you MUST have a "setup" call in your sprite subclasses;
        // apple forgot to include a "didAppear" for SKNodes
        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
    
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        
        // note that Apple do in fact include the "previous location"
        // in sprite kit touches. (In systems where they don't do that,
        // you just make a note of it each time.)
        
        let prev = t.previousLocation(in: parent!)
        let quickDelta = loc - prev
        position = position + quickDelta
    }
}
```

Comment: Note - the OP was asking about processing a touch anywhere on the scene (rather than on the sprite).  The code is identical.  Normally you have the code for a sprite on the sprite so I gave the examples like that here - you can copy and paste!  :)